# Is there any way to force Spring to check EL expressions on app start?

Tags: spring, el, spring-el

I have endpoints in `@RestController`s that look similar to this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/x")
public class XApiController
{

    // ...

    @PostMapping(...)
    @PreAuthorize("@apiAuthService.canAccessX(#headers)")
    public void saveX(...)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

These endpoints require the developer to make the `HttpHeaders` object available and name it correctly in the method declaration:

```
public void saveX(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers)
```

Our problem is that if this last step isn't done, the endpoint only fails at runtime when the endpoint is invoked. This means that issues from large refactors later (say, to change the `HttpHeaders` argument to `HttpServletRequest`) aren't easy to identify. Is there any way to tell Spring to validate these expressions are valid on app startup?

Comment: When there are EL expressions which can only be evaluated in runtime, how should spring know whether they are valid before runtime? Or am I missing something? Maybe you could trigger an integration test after startup?

Comment: I'm looking for something that verifies the types - something that should be able to be evaluated on app start - similar to the way HQL in `JpaRepository` instances are checked.

Comment: Ok, I got it. If beIN chatty wouldn't be that much discouraged in here, I'd suggest to use IntelliJ ;) maybe `org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser` is what you are searching for. You can use it for unit and integration testing.

Answer (score 0):

- I suggest you to create integration tests and then invoke `saveX` from the test to verify this before you deploy an application.

I would also state my opinion that if you want to have testable code with good quality - try to get rid of SpringEL as soon as possible. In my experience this approach proved as poorly testable, hardly maintainable and also introducing unnecessary complications to your source code.

In modern spring framework there are lots of ways to avoid writing SpringEl.

Answer (score 0):

Spring always validates all beans on start up. But your problem is not within validation your problem is test problem. The process of pre authorization is a runtime job. Spring can not know what to do with this expression spring just checks its syntax over SPEL rules.

1. You can create tests to check header.
2. You can increase your IDE inspection level of spring spel to error.
3. You can simply write a static method to get the headers without a rest parameter.